# NSDecimalNumber accuracy and compare

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

In the following test code the assert fails

```
NSDecimalNumber *num1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:1];
NSDecimalNumber *num2 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:6];
NSDecimalNumber *num3 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:3];
NSDecimalNumber *result1 = [num1 decimalNumberByDividingBy:num2]; // 1 ÷ 6
NSDecimalNumber *result2 = [result1 decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:num3]; // 1 ÷ 6 x 3 = 0.5

NSDecimalNumber *num4 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.5];
NSAssert([result2 compare:num4] == NSOrderedSame, @"Math error");
```

I understand this is to do with floating point accuracy, 1 ÷ 6 will introduce the issue. The result2 is 0.49999999999999999999999999999999999998 instead of 0.5.

I am trying to validate that two math expressions give the same result. Should I not use compare for this purpose but instead allow some small fractional difference between the two NSDecimalNumbers? Or perhaps I should use the decimalNumberByDividingBy:withBehavior: method and do some rounding?
I am not sure how to best proceed. Ideally result 2 would be 0.5 and I wouldn't need to hack the compare.

EDIT: This is how I am thinking of proceeding using the tolerance approach at the compare stage (not ideal) -

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)abs:(NSDecimalNumber *)num {
    if ([num compare:[NSDecimalNumber zero]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        // Number is negative. Multiply by -1
        NSDecimalNumber * negativeOne = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:1
                                                                      exponent:0
                                                                    isNegative:YES];
        return [num decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:negativeOne];
    } else {
        return num;
    }
}

- (void)test {
    NSDecimalNumber *num1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:1];
    NSDecimalNumber *num2 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:6];
    NSDecimalNumber *num3 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInteger:3];
    NSDecimalNumber *result1 = [num1 decimalNumberByDividingBy:num2]; // 1 ÷ 6
    NSDecimalNumber *result2 = [result1 decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:num3]; // 1 ÷ 6 x 3 = 0.5

    NSDecimalNumber *num4 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.5];
    NSDecimalNumber *tolerance = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithFloat:0.000000000001];
    NSDecimalNumber *delta = [self abs:[result2 decimalNumberBySubtracting:num4]];
    NSAssert([delta compare:tolerance] == NSOrderedAscending, @"Math error");
}
```

Comment: If you really want to test rational expressions for equality, then you have to do rational arithmetic: represent all numbers and intermediate results as `numerator/denominator`. There might be libraries available for rational arithmetic.